# jQuery Selectable inside an Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I am following jQuery ***Accordion*** examples provided at [Mikes.Netting](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/189/efficiently-displaying-hierarchical-data-with-the-jquery-accordion-in-razor-web-pages) and all the ***Selectable, etc.*** examples at [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

At present (see code below) the accordion works but I can only select child-items in the first accordion section. If I move the `<ul id="selectable">` bit right below `<div id="accordion">` then I can select everything but the accordion sections are always expanded and not collapsible.

Here are the scripts and code I am using on my asp.net web pages (razor) site.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#selectable").selectable();
    });
 </script>
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({ heightStyle: "content", collapsible: true, active: false });
        });
 </script>

 <div id="accordion">
                @foreach (var parent in keyParents) {
                    <h3><a href="#">@parent.Key</a></h3>
                    <div>
                        <ul id="selectable">
                            <li class="ui-widget-content">
                                <div><b>@parent.Key</b></div>
                            </li>
                            @foreach (var child in parent.OrderBy(p => p.KeywordChildName))
                            {
                                <li class="ui-widget-content">
                                    <div>@child.KeywordChildName</div>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
```

I should also mention this all sits inside a jQuery (tab). The fix to get the accordion to work in the tab was to simply to list the accordion script above the tab script although the accordion sits inside the tab. Hopefully there is a similar easy fix for this current issue. Finally, I want to be able to select just the parent element with no child items selected. At the moment i just list the parent element a second time right above the child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over an element that's targeted by ID. Change your `#selectable` to `.selectable` as the target of the `.selectable()`, and update the corresponding HTML: `<ul class="selectable">`.

IDs must be unique, so the iteration produces multiples of them.

Comment: With a little tweaking that fixed it. I changed the script from **id** to **class**: 
`<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".selectable").selectable();
    });
 </script>`
However to get it to work I had to add class to the HTML but leave in the ID:
 `<ul class="selectable" id="selectable">`
It seems to all be working properly now I just need to figure out how to save the selections (post the selected bits to my database) and retrieve those db selections everytime someone navigates to the page.